# PHP xpath query not working

Tags: php

I've got the following HTML code:

```html
<html><body><h1> <span class="mw-headline" id="Discussie_over_Titel">Discussie over  Titel</span></h1>
<div class="comments">
<div class="comment new">
<div class="newcommenttext">Klik op de button om een nieuwe opmerking te maken over <a href="/index.php/Titel" title="Titel">Titel</a></div><div class="buttons"><a href="/index.php/Speciaal:GegevensBewerken/Comment?Comment%5BWS-Comment-page%5D=Titel&amp;NewComment=Yes" title="" target="_self">Nieuwe opmerking</a></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="comments"><div>
</div><div class="commentBlock"><div class="comment" id="WikiSysop-"><div class="poster">Door <span class="usernamehighlight">WikiSysop</span> op  <span class="extradata">Type: Suggestie</span>
</div>
<div class="buttons"><a href="/index.php/Speciaal:GegevensBewerken/Comment?Comment%5BWS-Comment-page%5D=Discussie%3A%28door%20WikiSysop%20op%20%29&amp;NewComment=Yes" title="" target="_self">Reageer op deze opmerking</a><span class="collapse"><a href="/index.php?title=Collapse&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Collapse (de pagina bestaat niet)">Collapse</a></span></div><div class="content">Wat is dit nou weer?
</div>
</div>
</div><div class="commentBlock"><div class="comment" id="WikiSysop-"><div class="poster">Door <span class="usernamehighlight">WikiSysop</span> op  <span class="extradata">Type: Suggestie</span>
</div>
<div class="buttons"><a href="/index.php/Speciaal:GegevensBewerken/Comment?Comment%5BWS-Comment-page%5D=Discussie%3A%28door%20WikiSysop%20op%20Stiekem%29&amp;NewComment=Yes" title="" target="_self">Reageer op deze opmerking</a><span class="collapse"><a href="/index.php?title=Collapse&amp;action=edit&amp;redlink=1" class="new" title="Collapse (de pagina bestaat niet)">Collapse</a></span></div><div class="content">Mega mooi!
</div>
</div></div></div></div> <div class="comments">
<div class="comment new"><div class="newcommenttext">
Klik op de button om een nieuwe opmerking te maken over <a href="/index.php/Titel" title="Titel">Titel</a></div><div class="buttons"><a href="/index.php/Speciaal:GegevensBewerken/Comment?Comment%5BWS-Comment-page%5D=Titel&amp;NewComment=Yes" title="" target="_self">Nieuwe opmerking</a></div>
</div>
<p><br />
</p><p><br />
</p>
Klik hier om terug te keren naar <a href="/index.php/Titel" title="Titel">Titel</a>.</div>
</body></html>
```

To fetch all the comments I simply create a new dom parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($text);      
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$xpathResult = $xpath->query("//div[@class='comments']//div[@class='comments']");
```

But somehow the xpath query ALWAYS returns 0. Even when i use //body. Any body knows why?

Answer (score 0):

The Xpath query you are using will only grab nodes with class `comments` which are located (deep) inside another node with class `comments`.
With the HTML snippet you provided, it will return 1 node.

Comment: The explanation is right, however providing the right selector will surely lead the OP faster to an end.

Answer (score 0):

You duplicate selector, right using is:

```
$xpath->query("//div[@class='comments']"); // returns 3
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the duplicate entry:

```
$xpathResult = $xpath->query("//div[@class='comments']");
# 3 elements found
```

See [**a working demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/HpVoa4).